# Can Moderators Modify Bounty Text?

Tags: support, specific-question, bounty, moderators

Can moderators change the text on bounties? I would like to change the text that I placed on [this bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4907843/456814) to be friendlier and not inflammatory and insulting.

Here is what I would like to modify it to, if possible (Markdown source):

```
Firefox and IE users ***can choose how their browsers open popups, either in a
new window or a new tab,*** **this cannot be controlled through JavaScript,** as
is pointed out by [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907854/456814).
However, that answer lacks enough proof and details, **I'm looking for any sort
of documentation or source code that definitively proves this. Even screenshots
showing the Firefox and IE settings for popups would help a lot.**
```

This is the rendered Markdown:

> Firefox and IE users ***can choose how their browsers open popups, either in a
>   new window or a new tab,*** **this cannot be controlled through JavaScript,** as
>   is pointed out by [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907854/456814).
>   However, that answer lacks enough proof and details, **I'm looking for any sort
>   of documentation or source code that definitively proves this. Even screenshots
>   showing the Firefox and IE settings for popups would help a lot.**

Related question on Meta Stack Exchange, but not quite the same:

- [Can we have a way to edit bounty text?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112188/163250).

Comment: Also, is it possible for moderators to remove in-progress bounties altogether, if flagged and requested?

Comment: Bounties can technically be refunded, but this is generally not done.

Comment: @Bart cool, I just wanted to know if it was possible to "cancel" an in-progress bounty, I wouldn't ask for a refund in this case whether it was canceled or not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry, we can't edit existing bounties. We can remove them under special circumstances however.

I've canceled the bounty. Canceling bounties always causes the reputation to be returned to the user who started it, so you can put up a new bounty with the new text if you wish.

I didn't think I had to spell this out, but if anyone else comes across this answer and needs to have a bounty removed for exceptional reasons, the right thing to do is to **flag the question** on which they placed the bounty. Not hound answers like this one with comments.

Comment: My previous approach to improving the question was extremely misguided, thanks for fixing my mistake before it got really out-of-hand.

Comment: Well.. has anyone ever given any serious consideration to this solution: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141588/354720 ? Are there any plans to add such features in the future. I just placed my first bounty (including a message) only to find out after posting it that, apparently, composing such a message is a one time shot..