# How can I edit my bounty?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

I have added a bounty to this question:

[Web Security in IE VS Chrome & Firefox (bug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386532/web-security-in-ie-vs-chrome-firefox-bug)

Now I want to edit this bounty and need to change the bounty description, or increase the bounty size.

How can I do this?

Comment: Note this was [asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-text) (and is still pending) on the über-meta.

Comment: Also related: [Can Moderators Modify Bounty Text?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252857/464709)

Comment: Not Only Text. I want to change all details, Text, Points, and etc.. All

Comment: I doubt you would *ever* be able to change the amount. Currently you can't change anything though.

Comment: @user256103 short answer is you can't.  Once set, you can't change a bounty at all.

Answer (score 9):

> Now I want to edit this bounty and need to change the bounty
>   description, or increase the bounty size.

There is no way for you to edit the bounty description once you have submitted the bounty. So make sure you get it right before you start the bounty.

There is no way to increase/decrease the bounty amount after you have started the bounty. However, once the bounty ends and you still aren't satisfied with any answers then you can start a new bounty. However the new bounty must be double of the amount of your previous bounty on the same question. So if you did a 100 bounty, you'd have to do at least 200 bounty the next time. For other bounty rules, read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

Comment: Meaning my typo will now confuse the bounty's context forever? I typed `and` instead of `an` :'). A 5 minute grace period would really be appreciated..