# Allow bounty text to be edited

Tags: feature-request, bounty

No matter how many times I read something, it always seems like a grammar problem slips into my writing. Most places on SO, that can be corrected easily. However, when I left out a word in the bounty I just posted, I found I couldn't edit it to fix it - [How do you detect memory limits in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23506064/1454117).

Allowing bounties to be edited would be valuable as apparently I'm not the only one:

- [Can Moderators Modify Bounty Text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252857/1454117)
- [How can I edit my bounty?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253267/1454117)

Comment: I think at least giving this ability to mods is a good step

Comment: It's unbelievable that this can't be done? Isn't it obvious that EVERYTHING that you are allowed to write, you should be able to edit?

Comment: Still nothing about such feature?

Comment: Meta Stack Exchange dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-custom-message (from 2011) Though that never got a response either.