# Add feature to increase bounty reputation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, featured-page

It think it would be a good idea to let users increase bounty reputation when the bounty is still open. This should only go one way. One should be able to increase the bounty but should **not** be able to decrease it.

An example of this is when a user places a *100* reputation bounty on a question but the question did get the amount of attention or answer the user expects. Now, let's say that the user wants to increase the bounty to *400* but don't want to wait until the current bounty expires. This user should be able to increase the bounty to any valid amount they want. The only thing they can't do is decrease the bounty.

A simple *Edit Bounty* button with an input field should do it.

Is there any reason why this is a bad idea?

Comment: I'm not opposed to this, but what use cases do you see this being most valuable in?

Comment: Also handy when you put low bounty because you have low rep but then you few days, later, you got more rep and to increase that bounty that is still active.

Comment: I don't have an issue with allowing an in-flight adjustment personally...but I'm really not a fan of those use cases, since bounties in *no way* guarantee any speed of response.

Comment: When I said ASAP, I meant the likely of receiving answer before the 7 day bounty expires instead of receiving a poor answer that does not actually solve the problem. For some reason I do believe that adding big bounty will encourage people with more experience on that tag to drop their answer.

Comment: There's no guarantee of this, though.  In fact, I've seen just more users *in general* attempt to answer a bountied question, which doesn't mean that they have *any* semblance of experience whatsoever (and you can see that on [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44599053/1079354), which had a 500 rep bounty on it relatively recently, and ***lots*** of really bad answers which were deleted).

Comment: Ok. That clears some things up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now, let's say that the user wants to increase the bounty to 400 but don't want to wait until the current bounty expires.

Why not just wait?

If it's not about the "ASAP", [as you suggest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356110/add-feature-to-increase-bounty-reputation#comment510878_356118), then you're better off just waiting and starting a second bounty for the higher amount.

That way, you get twice the amount of exposure for the same "cost" in reputation.

Furthermore, this whole request makes a number of assumptions about the purpose of bounties and the motivations of answerers that I believe are fundamentally inaccurate.

In particular, it assumes that there exists people who know the answer to your question and *could* post it, but are simply choosing not to do so because you haven't offered them enough of an incentive yet. I've yet to come across such a person, and I'm pretty convinced that they do not exist.

The purpose of a bounty is to get your question "featured"—to increase the chances of the right pair of eyeballs seeing it. This happens just as adequately when the bounty is 50 points as when the bounty is 500 points. The only reason bounty amounts increase is because additional exposure time costs you more. The first round of exposure costs you 50 points, the second round of exposure costs you 100 points, and so on.

Your feature request assumes there is a person who finds your question and knows the answer, but says to themselves, "Ah, but the bounty is only 100! Not worth my time to answer yet; I'll wait until they up that sucker to 500." I just don't think this person is out there, and if they are, I'm not sure that I want to encourage their involvement with this site to any greater extent.

Comment: You are right. This was my initial assumption. I still believe being able to increase your bounty should be considered for another example I mentioned in the comment section: *"Also handy when you put low bounty because you have low rep but then you few days, later, you got more rep and to increase that bounty that is still active"*. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: I still don't see what the advantage of that would be. Let the current bounty lapse, and then if you *still* haven't gotten an answer, set another bounty for a higher amount. Now you get twice the exposure for the same cost. Or, if you got an answer in the meantime, you don't need to spend any more rep.

Answer (score 5):

On the surface the feature looks innocent, but I'm not comfortable with your intended use of it. You said:

> you need the answer ASAP but the answers that are already there did
>   not help at-all

I don't want to think about StackOverflow as a service that can give answers. Answers at all. Especially ASAP. Any bounty already makes a question stand out for a week. Normal question would be washed away from the front page in, say, 1 hour. If such extended exposure is not enough to get good answers, then either the question is really tough, or its quality may be improved.

Quite often, when a person writes in the question that he desperately needs an answer ASAP, it repels people from answering. Maybe because quite often such questions are of low quality as well. The act of increasing the bounty amount indicates that the person is desperate and it may have an opposite effect.

On the other hand, if I'm not mistaken, right now nothing stops you from awarding the bounty without waiting for it to expire and then immediately starting a new higher bounty. The new bounty has to be twice as large as previous. Do you have to wait before starting the second bounty? I didn't find such requirement in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

On yet another hand, it may be useful to be able to edit (or rather extend) the explanatory text under the bounty. Right now you can't change it at all. I should ask it as another feature-request question. ... It has been asked before ([Allow bounty text to be edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255217/allow-bounty-text-to-be-edited) , [Can we have a way to edit bounty custom message?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-custom-message)).

Comment: I think that everyone is too focused on the "ASAP" I said in the comment section which I just removed. It's not the main reason and it's just one of them. *This answer would have been helpful if it focused on the question instead of just that comment.* When  I said ASAP, I didn't mean answering the question right away since a question with a bounty is already 2 days old and 2 days old is not ASAP. I meant receiving an answer before that 7 days the bounty is active runs out.

Comment: "*right now nothing stops you from awarding the bounty without waiting for it to expire and then immediately starting a new higher bounty.*" If you have a complicated question with a poor answer that is some how up-voted by other users, that answer does not deserve the bounty. That's the point.

Comment: @Programmer, I understand your point. Yes, I was too focused on the "ASAP" comment. I agree with what Cody Gray says in his answer.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for you answer too.