# How can I handle broken bounty text?

Tags: support, status-completed, bounty

I left out a word in [a bounty text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76259392/3789665), inverting the meaning of a half-sentence.

How can I handle such?

(Was *[sketch a solution] faster than O((nm)²) - or Ω((nm)²)*, but should have been *- or **prove** Ω((nm)²)*.)

Comment: I'm aware of several questions about editing bounty texts and privileges that should be required ((So *No, not really*.)) which is why I didn't ask about editing one more time, but handling). And problems created by allowing changes after significant time - one hour?

Comment: There is no option to update that text. If it is really troublesome (but think in terms of an unfortunate typo that ends up in being an insult) a moderator might cancel the bounty, refund it to you and then you can try again. But you need a nice mod for that ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "handling" as opposed to "editing" the typo in the bounty text. Users can't do it currently, so you could ask a mod https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252857 (unlikely to be done for a non-offensive typo, but you could try). You could also upvote the FR https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255217, though that won't help right now.

Comment: @greybeard You could post a comment below the question in which you explain the typo and show what your actual bounty text was supposed to be

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz which is what I decided to do once the post isn't locked any more…

Comment: As the dupe says, you can't. It is effectively a system bug, whether by design or not. But since you just set this bounty 2 hours ago, I'm going to be nice and clear the bounty so you can re-set it with a new message. The comments were locked because there were already too dang many of them (29 at the time of locking, now deleted). As the lock message and mod comment says, that's beyond the purpose of comments. That kind of important information shouldn't be in a comment *anyway* (cc @samcarter), even if the comments weren't locked. Put it in a edit!!

Comment: (`too [many comments]` including mine but for the first one, putting in parentheses to later check and probably delete or not.) Thanks @CodyGray - never registered one could leave an entire short story there.